# Punctuation for "therefore"

Tags: punctuation

I wrote this sentence

> We show that our proposed system provides robust and maintainable wrappers, which are not tailored to the HTML structure of the page, **therefore,** they can be employed to gather and integrate data from various Web sites.

Did I used the comma correctly before and after "therefore" to relate the sentences? What is the rule?

what is the difference of these alternatives?

> 1) We show that our proposed system provides robust and maintainable wrappers, which are not tailored to the HTML structure of the page. **Therefore,** they can be employed to gather and integrate data from various Web sites.
>
> 2) We show that our proposed system provides robust and maintainable wrappers, which are not tailored to the HTML structure of the page; **therefore,** they can be employed to gather and integrate data from various Web sites.

Comment: Have you tried searching for "punctuation with therefore" (with quotes)?  I find plenty of info online.

Comment: @VictorBazarov I tried to make my question more specific.

Comment: I see your updated question.  First of all, I don't think that "*therefore*" needs a comma after it.  It does need a comma before it, usually, if it starts another clause.  Whether to separate two sentences by a full stop or a semicolon is irrelevant to the fact that you use '*therefore*'.

Comment: @VictorBazarov if I got you right, you mean it must be in a new sentence and no need for comma? I guess if I have had used "thus", then I could use the second sentence!

Comment: Yes, I think it's essentially the same as with 'thus'. I am not a native speaker, though.

Comment: I don't have a problem with any of them, however I am not a writer. Probably there is some technical rule. I would prefer 1) because it breaks up what otherwise is a really long sentence (three clauses + conjunctions).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a semicolon before therefore as it introduces a complete sentence joined with the first independent clause.

"........of the page; therefore, they can be........."

Comment: What is its difference with beginning a new sentence using "...Therefore, ...".

Comment: I think the difference is subtle.  In the former case  (; therefore)  the pause is shorter than t hat in the latter case (Therefore,) between the two sentences.